# How to propagate non-zero exit code for input redirection in bash?

Tags: bash, redirect, exit-code

I know about "set -o pipefail" for propagating exit codes for pipes. However, I want to do something similar for input redirection. Specifically, I want this to happen:

```
$ cat <(echo abc; exit 1) 
abc
$ echo $?
1
```

The current behavior is that the last line is '0' instead of '1'.

How do I accomplish this? No, I can't use a pipe. The example I gave is just a simplified test case. In practice I'm taking input from multiple sources.

Comment: A big difference between pipes and process redirection is that pipes are inherently linear. With process redirection, you can have multiple subshells in parallel.

Comment: Since the example code doesn't work, can you provide some more details? Must all the processes stop as soon as one of them fails, or is it sufficient to detect an error after the fact? Does it matter which exit code is used (as long as it's non-zero)? If you're taking input from multiple sources, a more complex (but hopefully minimal) example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with input redirection I'm afraid. Maybe have the processes that provide input write their exit status to a file and check it later?

Answer (score 0):

I've an example here using a temp file as suggested by @Lars:

```
tmp=`mktemp`; sort -mk1 <(zcat 1.gz || rm -f $tmp) <(zcat 2.gz || rm -f $tmp) && rm $tmp
```

The return code will be 'success' (zero) iff sort and the two zcats are successful.